# browser.getProcessedConfig in Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, protractor, end-to-end

Protractor exposes a [`getProcessedConfig()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.getProcessedConfig) function on a global `browser` object. The documentation does not give enough information on when this function can be helpful:

> Get the processed configuration object that is currently being run.
>   This will contain the specs and capabilities properties of the current
>   runner instance.
>
> Set by the runner.

What use cases does `getProcessedConfig()` cover? Has someone used it before and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getProcessedConfig()
```

Allows all the configuration values from a project to be viewable, including configurations and parameters.
To easily view the output into the terminal, try this:

```
browser.getProcessedConfig().then(console.log);
```

The processedConfigs can also be useful if you need to access specific values in the configurations, including framework parameters, multiCapabilities and options.  I am currently using it to access a configuration value in my onPrepare() method, within my protractor config.js file.